# 401 unauthorized error in springboot with no response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm implementing a simple REST controller in springboot with token authentication.
Everything works fine but when a user is not authenticated, springboot will return a 401 error with no response body.

Is it possible for me to return a custom JSON object with a message such as "Please provide a valid token."?
Springboot version is 3

I've tried to implement custom exception handlers but not sure if that's the correct path to achieve this result.

Comment: 401 says "This resource requires authentication and you didn't provide it. If you resubmit with valid authentication, I will let you access the resource".  Everything you need to know is already embodied in the 401 status code.  What benefit would you gain by adding a response body?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it. For example if I try to do a get request to  an unspecified endpoint it will at least give a JSON object with timestamp, etc. Maybe it's not best practice to do that with 401 but I'd just like to know if it's possible.

Comment: Please have a look at this issue, discussing a very similar subject : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5985

Answer (score 0):

you can [create a custom authentication failure handler](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler). `Spring security` is the module that lets setup an authentication mechanism.